# Do light's electric and magnetic components oscillate in physical space?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, speed-of-light

I have heard that light is a transverse wave which is necessary for effects like polarisation, but I am unsure of what exactly this means. Is this saying that light's electric and magnetic components oscillate in perpendicular directions of three dimensional space? i.e could the electric (or magnetic) component literally oscillate say 'up' and 'down' making the electric field strength of points in space above or below the wave stronger or weaker according to the light's phase?

If not, then what could it mean for light to be a transverse wave, and how does polarisation work in this context?

Thanks in advance for any help with understanding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really, this is a question about how to picture the electric field itself.  Mathematically, an electric field is a collection of vectors, one for each point in space.  The vector attached to a point in space corresponds to the strength and direction of the electric field vector *at that point*. To get a feeling for what this means, suppose the electric field vector at point $\vec{x}$ in space is $\vec{E}(x)$. Then, imagine we place a charge $q$ at point $\vec{x}$. The charge feels the electric field vector $\vec{E}(x)$, resulting in a force $\vec{F}=q\vec{E}(x)$. Neither of these vectors ($\vec{E}$ or $\vec{F}$) have any sort of *spatial* extent; instead, the meaning of the vector is to represent what's going on *at that point in space*.

In that sense,

> i.e could the electric (or magnetic) component literally oscillate say 'up' and 'down' making the electric field strength of points in space above or below the wave stronger or weaker

is not a correct way of thinking about the electric field and the oscillation of the electric field vectors making up an electromagnetic wave.  For those details, see below.  Again, the oscillation of the electric field vector represents the change in the electric field vector *at that point in space*; the visual representation of an arrow in space is misleading in that way.

---

Thus, when we talk about an electromagnetic wave, we can imagine that at each point in space, there is an electric field vector, and each of these electric field vectors varies in time. For the simplest case of a plane electromagnetic wave, the electric field vector $\vec{E}(x,t)$ at point $\vec{x}$ varies in time as $\vec{E}(x,t) = \vec{E}_0\cos(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}-\omega t)$, which means that at all times, the electric field vector points along the direction parallel or anti-parallel to $\vec{E}_0$ while its amplitude grows and shrinks according to the $\cos$ function shown.

If the wave is transverse, this means that the electric field vector at each point in space must be perpendicular to the direction of propagation ($\vec{k}$), i.e., that $\vec{E}_0\cdot\vec{k}=0$.  The animation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#/media/File:Electromagneticwave3D.gif) is useful to visualize what a plane electromagnetic wave might look like, as the direction of the electric field is always perpendicular to the direction of motion of the wave, except we have to understand the following:

1. There is actually an oscillating electromagnetic field *everywhere* in space (if this is a plane wave), and this animation shows only the field along an axis parallel to the $y$-axis.
2. The vectors shown don't actually "span" any amount of space. Importantly, those vectors represent the strength of the field *at the point in space* that their tails are attached to, and hence only an electric charge placed *at that point in space* will feel that electric field vector.

Comment: I am not entirely certain what you are saying in reference to the direction of the fields, does this mean that for a positive point charge located along the path of the light wave it will be pushed in the direction of the electric field associated with the light wave with a force proportional to the size of the wave at that point? If not what does the 'direction' physically indicate?

Comment: The direction of the field at a point indicates the direction of the force a point like charged particle at that position will experience, given by the Lorentz force law, with the magnitude of the field of course determining the magnitude of the force

Comment: @DMMiller Your interpretation is correct (at least for the electric force, which is all I talked about in the post). Including the magnetic field (also existing at each point in space and oscillating in the same way as the electric field) requires you to use the Lorentz force law to compute the force on a charged particle at that point, as a previous comment mentioned.  This will cause a charged particle to move around when the wave moves the spot where the region where the particle is located, and so the particle will sample different fields in different places.